# How do I remove trailing whitespace, then the last character?

Tags: ruby

For example: `The fox is red.x________` (Consider underscores as spaces). How can I remove the white space and the x?

**Edit:**
What if there are several lines like this?

```
The fox is red.x________
The fox is grey.x________
The fox is blue.x________
The fox is green.x________
```

Comment: [rstrip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-rstrip) and [chop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chop) will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go over each line, and chop it:

```
text.lines.map(&:rstrip).map(&:chop).join($/)
# => The fox is red.
# => The fox is grey.
# => The fox is blue.
# => The fox is green.
```

Comment: Just note that this way you are missing a newline at the end of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the original question:

```
"The fox is red.x        ".sub(/. *\z/, "")
# => "The fox is red."
```

Answer to the question after it was changed:

```
text.gsub(/. *$/, "")
```

Comment: I'd recommend using \s instead of a literal space character in the regex.

Comment: @Coenwulf That would change the behaviour.

Comment: But since the original poster asked about removing "white space" it may imply that tab characters need to be removed as well. In any case, removing white space is what was requested...

Comment: @Coenwulf Tab is not a white space; it is a white space character.

Answer (score 0):

Sawa has a good answer. If however you need to remove all white space characters (as you posted) you could use this slightly altered regex:

```
text.gsub(/.\s*$/, "")
```